# Simple regex question to parse similar things in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, parsing

Is there a way to gather all links that has a specific domain in a string where they only include ones that are either:

```
href="http://yahoo.com/media/news.html"
```

or

```
>http://yahoo.com/media/news.html<
```

So basically links either prefixed by `href="` and ends with `"`

or

links that are surrounded by `><`.

I tried to use `Regex ( "href=\"([^\"]*)\"></A>" )` but didn't match anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string[] inputs = { "href=\"http://yahoo.com/media/news.html\"", ">http://yahoo.com/media/news.html<" };

string pattern = @"(?:href=""|>)(?<Url>http://.+?)[<""]";
foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Url"].Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** another approach is to use look-arounds so that the text is matched but not captured. This allows you to use `Match.Value` directly instead of using groups. Try this alternate approach below.

```
string pattern = @"(?<=href=""|>)http://.+?(?=<|"")";
foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2:** per the request in the comments here is a pattern that will not match URLs that contain "..." in the text.

```
string pattern = @"(?<=href=""|>)http://(?!.*\.{3}).+?(?=<|"")";
```

The only change is the addition of `(?!.*\.{3})` which is a negative look-ahead that allows the pattern to match if the specified suffix is absent. In this case it checks that the "..." is absent. If you need to match at least 3 dots then use `{3,}`.

Comment: Thanks this works, but is it possible to just get the links? I am getting the links like ">coollink<"

Comment: @Joan: please show me what your input looks like. Is it different from the 2nd item I use in the `inputs` array?

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. My input is exactly same, but I get the match results like this:

>http://yahoo.com/media/news.html<

So it includes the >< too.

Comment: Btw I am getting the results, using match.Value. Should I use the groups like you did?

Comment: @Joan: yes the group is crucial to the way I setup the regex. Using match.Value returns the entire match which is why you see the >< characters.

Comment: @Joan: great! I updated my post with an alternate approach that allows you to use `Match.Value` if you prefer that. For large documents the first approach will probably perform better.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, so using groups is faster in performance than directly using Value?

Comment: @Joan: no that's not what I meant. Using patterns with look-arounds usually perform slower than patterns that don't use them. I wouldn't avoid them without testing since they are extremely useful and make pattern matching easier at times.

Comment: Actually finished the parsing but have one more question if you don't mind. If there was a string inside the string where if it exists you don't want to match it, would it be doable with regex? Or should I just skip that result out using standard logic like I do now. Basically I am trying to avoid links with "..." in them.

Comment: Also Ahmad, it looks like there is a problem. When I get the matches, I checked some of the matches and they only received one or the other. So for instance in the website if a link is coded like a link then it will have both >< and the "" version but I only get one of them which in my case seems to be ><s not ""s, which contain the full link.

Comment: @Joan I'll have to get back to you on the earlier question. As for the last one, are you using `Regex.Matches`? Can you post a representative sample of the input so I'm sure I understand the issue?

Comment: @Joan: please see my 2nd edit. It handles the "..." scenario.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I have cropped the website stream that I am using. It shows all cases, which are links with ""s, and ><s. Also shows the ... case. Basically what it is, is if a link is inside href="", then it's formatted as a link inside the forum, which will have both the display text (links between ><) and the link itself. But if they just code it as text, then they will appear fine and there will be only 1 link that's inside ><. Does it make sense?

For me I only need the full link which is always getting the href="link", and if that's not available then getting the link between >link<.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, did the sample helped? If it's not doable don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

```
(href="[^"]*")|(>[^<]*<)
```

Starts with href=", followed by characters that are not ", ending with "

or

Starts with >, followed by characters that are not <, ending with <

Comment: Thanks alot. Do I have to escape these characters? It doesn't let me to compile because of red underlines in the editor. I just encapsulated it with "".

Comment: Yes - if you surround this with " to make a string, you'll need to escape the " within the string.

Comment: Note, this just matches literally what you asked for.  It doesn't take anything else into account, such as ensuring there is a valid URL being captured, looking at what kind of tag it is, etc.

Comment: Thanks got it. In the matches, I get many (><) mathes though. Is it because they fit the criteria too? I actually made it ( "(href=yahoo\"[^\"]*\")|(>[^<]*<)" )" but still picks up.

Comment: Ok now got it to do that. It works. One last thing I want to ask is, if it's possible not to capture the >< with the link?

Comment: Yes, put the parts you don't want to capture in look-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
http=\"(.+)\"
```

Comment: Thanks I tried Regex ( "http=\"(.+)\"" ), with  pattern.Matches ( text ) but didn't match anything.